# how to pass data from activity to fragment in android without budle?

Tags: android, parsing, fragment

**This is the activity class of my project**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs_activity);

    String LicID = "DATA"
    Fragment FragmentDetail = new FragmentDetail();
    Bundle data  = new Bundle();
    data.putString("data",LicID);

    FragmentDetail.setArguments(data);

    ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentDetail(),"Detail");


    viewp.setAdapter(adapter);
    tablay.setupWithViewPager(viewp);
}
```

}

**This is my fragmentDetail activity. and it is a tab fragment...**

```
public class FragmentDetail extends Fragment {

public FragmentDetail() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment,container,false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    String LicID = getArguments().getString ("data");
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+LicID+" ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}
This code is not work.app crash without any error.... please help. thank you

Comment: You project crashes, most probably because there is no place in the Detail Fragment to retrieve arguments that sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in tab_activity:

```
 public String LicID = "DATA"
```

When you want to access this variable from the fragment attached to activity,

in Detail Fragment :

```
((tab_activity) (getActivity)).LicID
```

so you don't have to pass arguments to the fragment and use bundle for this. If you need further assistance, please show your logcat

Comment: according this in my project  `String abc = (ActivityName(tab_activity())).LicID;` But **ActivityName** is not existing keyword. my activity name is **tab_activity** and fragment name is **FragmentDetail** . I post the drive link of my project in below. can u find the problem using it. thank you. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ufkOatg3XXZgKwFqczh10dX5D-NQX0IK)

Comment: No, not like this, You should put the Activity name there. Because I can't see your Activity name I can't write it; it should be like this:

String abc = ((Tabs_Activity)  getActivity).LicID    

Note: You should change Tab_Activity part with the proper Activity name

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you set argument to one fragment:

```
Fragment FragmentDetail = new FragmentDetail();
Bundle data  = new Bundle();
data.putString("data",LicID);

FragmentDetail.setArguments(data);
```

And add to adapter another fragment:

```
adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentDetail(),"Detail");
```

Please, try to use the same fragment.

Comment: its not work. I set adapter and pass the data to the same Fragment..